# Android ImageButton not working

Tags: android, imagebutton

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/one_button"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/by1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/two_button"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/2"
        android:contentDescription="@string/by2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/three_button"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:background="@drawable/3"
        android:contentDescription="@string/by3" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/four_button"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:background="@drawable/4"
        android:contentDescription="@string/by4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.one_button :
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.GROUP"));
            break;
        case R.id.two_button :
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.ATOZ"));
            break;
        case R.id.three_button :
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.ATOZ"));
            break;
        default :
            break;
    }

}
```

Now, if I press `one_button` or `two_button` all works as expected but if i press `three_button` nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. - Manifest is ok because `two_button` starts the desired activity.

Thanks,

favolas

Comment: I am surprised to see that your first 2 buttons are even working this should throw the compilation errors as the button ids cannot start with numbers.

Comment: It was only for example. Edited my question. Not getting compiler errors not even warnings

Comment: Have you assigned onClickListener to 3rd button?

Comment: @Favolas :  **but if i press three_button nothing happens.** means? what you want to do on three_button  try to make a toast on three_button   click

Comment: @PareshMayani Yes. I have done that. If button 2 works, and if button 3 sends to the same activity it should work also

Comment: @imrankhan Means that it should open the same activity as button two (they should do the same thing) and nothing happens

Comment: PLease post the whole code that you are Using as Complete Checking only will lead to the Solution.Put the class that describes this Button.

Comment: @HareshChaudhary Was a simple mistake. Forgot to declare and initialize the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set onClickListener on 3_button.

```
ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.3_button);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Yes. public class MyClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to do that :( So simple but sometimes, the things that should be right in front of your eyes tend to be invisable.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have button names starting with numbers

Try to change the `Button Ids` to something as `button_1` instead of `1_button`.

It will work.

Might be you did not add listener on the third button...

Comment: Sorry. It was for example only. Edited my question